# How to pass two Subjects/Action streams as HTTP Params in a GET request to return a single object/Array of objects in Angular using RxJS?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

**OBJECTIVE:** I want to **GET** a single object and/or a range of objects from my backend service by passing in user inputs as HTTP params using RxJS.
For Example, I am using declarative RxJS and so I have two Subjects (Action streams) to grab the input from the user when they hit Submit. I want to pass those Subjects values, **as HTTP params**, into my http request in order to get either the specified bay object, or a range of bays.
The first Subject/UserInput will always be mandatory, whereas the second Subject/UserInput will be optional. So if someone enters 4 for the first input, and then nothing for the second input. The backend will accept both inputs as 4 and 'null' because nothing was put in. If that's the case, return the bay that has a bay Number of 4. If there is a second input like 6, return a range of bays from 4 -> 6, if they exist.

**The Issue:** How do I pass those two Subjects as http params using declarative RxJS?

Here are my two subjects and their method, as well as my attempt at the HTTP request in my `bay-service.ts` file.

```
  private bayStartSelectedSubject = new Subject<number>();
  baySelectedAction$ = this.bayStartSelectedSubject.asObservable();

  private bayEndSelectedSubject = new Subject<number>();
  bayEndSelectedAction$ = this.bayEndSelectedSubject.asObservable();

  selectedBayChanged(selectedBayStartNumber: number, selectedBayEndNumber?: number): void {
    this.bayStartSelectedSubject.next(selectedBayStartNumber);
    this.bayEndSelectedSubject.next(selectedBayEndNumber);
  }

  private HandlingUnitResponseUrlSecondary = 'http://localhost:8080/sbtemplate/readBayInventory';


bayOrBays$ = combineLatest([
    this.baySelectedAction$,
    this.bayEndSelectedAction$
  ])
    .pipe(
      map(([bayStart, bayEnd]) => {
        mergeMap(() => this.http.get<HuResponse>(`${this.HandlingUnitResponseUrlSecondary}/COS/${bayStart}/${bayEnd}`))
      })
    );
```

Here is where I grab the user inputs in my `bay-page.ts` file, and call their method to emit the user inputs value:

```
onSubmit() {
    this.bayService.selectedBayChanged(this.bayForm.get('bayStart').value, this.bayForm.get('bayEnd').value);
    if(!this.invalidBay) {
      this.bayDoesNotExistError = true;
      this.selectedBay = this.bayForm.get('bayStart').value;
      this.vibration.vibrate(500);
      console.log('Vibrating for 3 second...')
    } else {
      this.navCtrl.navigateForward([`/results/`]);
    }
```

I know the code doesn't look great, but I can't find any information on this. Thanks for the help!

**Also** Here is the backend API that I am trying to hit:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/readBayInventory/{centerId}/{beginBayId}/{endBayId}", method = GET)
    public ResponseEntity<HUResponse> readBayInventory(@PathVariable String centerId, @PathVariable int beginBayId, @PathVariable(required = false) int endBayId) {
```

Comment: Hi Donny, thanks for your question. Please can you be more specific and ask it in a paragraph and a snippet or two of code? Makes it a lot easier to help, that's a lot of words mate!

Comment: Are you wanting pictures of my code? I had posted a question about something else and they said to type my code into StackOverflow. So, I'm getting mixed results, sorry. I don't know how else to explain it except that I have two Subjects that take a user input, whatever the user inputs, I want to pass as http params in a GET request to retrieve a single/Range of bay objects.

Comment: No probs, I remember when I joined too, a little frustrating at times. Just write your question and the code it relates to.

Comment: Okay, I hope I made it better and not worse. I really don't know how else to elaborate on my question..

Comment: what's the issue you run into? The get http didn't get called?

Comment: The current code (The http request) returns an Observable<void>. I don't know what operator or what direction to take it in order to make it return Observable<HuResponse>?  I know I need higher-order mapping because if I don't, it will be of type Observable<Observable<HuResponse>> But I want to return whatever the result is, as an array back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change the way you declare `bayOrBays` and move to this form

```
const bayOrBays$ = combineLatest([
  baySelectedAction$,
  bayEndSelectedAction$
]).pipe(
  concatMap(([bayStart, bayEnd]) => this.http.get<HuResponse>(`${this.HandlingUnitResponseUrlSecondary}/COS/${bayStart}/${bayEnd}`))
);
```

This code basically means that every time one of the 2 Subjects emits a new value, you will trigger the http call and return its result. `concatMap` is one of the so called "higher level operators", i.e. is an operator that takes a function which returns an Observable and returns the value emitted by such Observable (in other words it "flattens" the inner Observable returned by the function passed in as input).

Other "higher level operators" are `mergeMap` (aka `flatMap`), `switchMap` and `exahustMap`. All have slightly different behaviors, but for http calls usually `concatMap` is a safe default. You may get some inspiration on how to use rxJs in common http related use cases from [this article](https://betterprogramming.pub/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a).

Finally, the reason why currently you get `Observable<void>` as type of `bayOrBays$` is in part related to the fact that the function you pass to `mergeMap` does not return anything. Remember that if you use curly-braces to define the body of a function, you have to explicitly use a `return` statement to return something. On the contrary, if you use the one-line format for the body (i.e. without curly-braces) the function returns whatever is the result of the execution of that one line.

So, this format (which is what you used) does not return anything

```
const myFunction = () => {
  doStuff();
}
```

while both of these formats return whatever `doStuff()` returns

```
const myFunction = () => {
  return doStuff();
}

const myFunction = () => doStuff()
```

Comment: Yeah, this is kind of what I was going towards. Is my approach the right way by getting the user inputs and passing them like I am to my HTTP request? Thank you for your response! I'm starting to understand RxJS better and I really like it. I just still have some overhead that takes me a little bit to wrap my head around! Thank you!